# Executing string in Python exceeding the max string length

Tags: python, exec, maxlength

I want to execute my code saved in the variable `texto` that exceeds the max string length (8000) that `exec()` accepts.

I found [this post](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/max-string-length-for-exec-command) where it is said that using `+` the problem can be solved by dividing the string into strings with length <8000. So if `texto` has length 11000 I can divide it into three parts of length 4000, 4000 and 3000 respectively and execute `text` like this:

```
exec(first_part_texto + second_part_texto + third_part_texto)
```

The problem is that `texto` takes different lengths and I cannot write the previous `exec()` manually because I do not know how many parts text will have, so I did this:

```
global list_of_texto
n=4000
list_of_texto = [str(texto[i:min(i+n, len(texto))]) for i in range(0, len(texto), n)]
exec_text = "exec("
for i in range(len(list_of_texto)):
    exec_text += f"list_of_texto[{i}]+"
exec_text = exec_text[:-1] + ", globals())"
exec(exec_text)
```

It works, but I was wondering if someone could think of a better way of doing this. Because I know that using `exec` is not recommended and I am using two nested `exec`.

Comment: I've never heard of such a length limit, but I can pretty well guarantee that if you want to pass something that long to `exec` you are doing something wrong. It's rare to have a legitimate use for `exec` *at all*. If there *were* a limit, then your approach *could not possibly* work around it, because the string concatenation happens before the function is called.

Comment: Looking at the link you provide, *it has nothing to do with the `exec` function in Python*. It is about SQL.

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible, because you are working around a problem that doesn't appear to exist, in order to implement something that probably doesn't make sense to do in the first place, for unexplained reasons.

Comment: I have many huge files describing a list of lists that describes a dataset and that can be read by Python, it looks like `list_to_read=[[423,23,"yes",[92,12,8]], [32,342,"no",[12,3,17]],...]`. And the only way I can think about to get the information in those lists is to use `exec()` I hope that shows why I need to do this.

Comment: And even though that approach seems counter-intuitive it works. I was also surprised by the fact that the concatenation is not done before the function is called.

Comment: Did you try importing the file as a module? Did you try removing the `list_to_read=` and using it as JSON? Why exactly does the file look this way? Was it *supposed* to be Python source code? Why?

Comment: I can guarantee you that the concatenation is done before the function call. The reason it works is because *Python does not have the limit in question*.

Comment: @TeresodelRíoAlmajano [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) has no such limit; try `exec('x = [' + ','.join(['1']*100_000) + ']')`.